# identificar registros duplicados con doble condición

Tags: mysql

Tengo este registro duplicado:

[image: Imagen]

la forma de identificarlos es porque tiene el mismo **`codigo_producto`** y mismo numero **`pedido`**

Necesito saber cuantos datos mas de esta forma tengo en mi base de datos.

Cabe destacar que por ejemplo este mismo **`codigo_producto`** puede tener un numero **`pedido`** distinto, y ese no habria que considerar ya que no es duplicado.

estructura tabla:

```
 CREATE TABLE comex_014 (

 codigo_producto VARCHAR(21) DEFAULT NULL,
 pedido INT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 invoice VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL )
```

Comment: ¿Podrias compartir la estructura de las tablas de donde estas obteniendo la consulta que presentas?

Comment: listo. adjuntada

Comment: Intentaste algo? esto se soluciona con un group by...

Comment: Agrupalos todos con un group by

Comment: logre solucionarlo, muchas gracias ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solucion:

```
 SELECT codigo_producto, COUNT(pedido) 
 FROM comex_014  
 GROUP BY pedido, codigo_producto 
 HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```